# Python Conundrum 2: Guess The Place

Tags: knowledge, visual, calculation-puzzle, rebus, computer-puzzle

[Python Conundrum: The Series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A85112%20title%3A%22Python%20Conundrum%22)

---

**The key:**
[image]

**The puzzle:**

```
a = ???
b = ???
c = ???
d = ???
e = ???
f = ???

g = f * a ** a * (e * 2 - 28 // c) + 622 + b
h = g * a - (d * (31 - c) + 60 // b)
s = a * b * c * d * e * f * g

sh = ''.join([str(s), str(h)])

for index, char in enumerate(sh):
    if index % 2 != 0:
        num = ''.join([str(sh[index-1]), str(sh[index])])
        print(chr(int(num)), end='')
```

Partial output of the script (* means hidden character):

```
***F*****N
```

**Main task:** find the meaning of what the python script prints with the right key used.

**Optional task:** solve the key.

Comment: rot13(Hfvat gur zbfg "nccnerag" cbffvovyvgvrf, n = {2, 45}, q = {23, 39, 59}, p = {7}, V pbhyqa'g svaq nal cynvagrkg zngpu sbe o,r,s va enatr [1, 200]. Znlor fbzr yngreny-guvaxvat vf erdhverq, naq gur pbqr vf abg rira zrnag gb or rkrphgrq?)

Comment: @LukasRotter - rot13(Lbh ner ba gur evtug genpx. Gur xrl pbagnvaf 6 inevnoyrf juvpu ner abg ybatre guna 3 qvtvgf, nf fubja va gur pbqr. Gur pbqr vf zrnag gb or rkrphgrq, ab yngreny guvaxvat vf erdhverq.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the location is

> [Whiterun](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Whiterun_(Skyrim))

If you execute the code with the right values, it outputs

> #FFFFFFRUN

which is

> hex color #FFFFFF (= white) + run

The keys are derived as follows:

> `a = 2` (a square has 2 dimensions) 
>  `b = 5 = V (Roman)` (22th letter in English)
>  `c = 7` (colors in a rainbow)
>  `d = 23 = 12 * 2 - 1` (a regular icosahedron has 12 vertices)
>  `e = 61 = 2 * 30 + 1` (30 spokes in each wheel)
>  `f = 877 = "8 7 7"` (8-ball; N = Nitrogen = 7th element)

Comment: @BenjaminWang I have no idea, my best guess (which is a bad guess) is that its because Titanium has 5 naturally occuring isotopes.

Comment: My first intuition for f's (right part) is the diatomic nitrogen (triple bond). Maybe that's relevant(?)

Comment: @BenjaminWang - I can tell you why is b = 5 if you are curious :D

Comment: @BenjaminWang - b = 5 because V is **22nd** letter of the English alphabet, which means 5 in Roman numeric system. f = 877 because the arrow points at **8 ball** (a pool game). 8 ball is black and is usually in the center when starting an 8 ball game. 77 comes from nitrogen's (N) **atomic number 7**, if you put N and N together you should get 77 and then 877 when you combine it with 8 before. I know it's too much to guess and because of that I created an opportunity to bruteforce the script if you have part of the key solved.

Comment: Thanks @webadventurer . While it does seem like you also reverse-engineered `f` as the puzzle creator, I understand that is unavoidable for "hash functions" like these. It's good that you gave three digits `???` as the clues (although to nitpick, numbers can't start with `0` so maybe `int("???")` is better :))